# Magento2 - Get the newly added custom form post data from checkout form

Tags: magento2, checkout, data, post

I have a custom form in my checkout page in the area shippingAddress at before-form. I am using the event checkout_onepage_controller_success_action, but `$this->_request->getPost();` does not give me any data. It returns an empty array. Can anyone suggest how data can be saved into a new table from checkout form.

Comment: How you added that form?
And where you want to that data?

Comment: yes I have added that form in shippingAddress area in checkout_index_index in my custom module. I am using the even checkout_onepage_controller_success_action to get the data from the form and save it in a new table. In the observer I have used $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
  $orderId = $orderIds[0];
  $data = $this->request->getPost(); But this does not give me the post data from the new form. The array is empty in fact.